# Mui-datatables fixed column on scroll - (left or right)

Tags: reactjs, mui-datatable

How to fix the column on the screen during the scroll? Using the Mui-datatables library, like datatables on doc. [doc](https://datatables.net/reference/option/fixedColumns#Examples)

In the [mui-datatables](https://github.com/gregnb/mui-datatables) there is a fixedSelectColumn property, but I was unable to select the column or configure the scroll.

My options :

```
 const options = {
        filter: true,
        filterType: 'multiselect',
        textLabels : TextLabels,
        responsive: 'scroll',
        fixedHeader: true,
        tableBodyHeight: '100%',
        selectableRows: false,
        fixedSelectColumn: true,


    };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `fixedSelectColumn` prop is for the "selection" elements, i.e., the check boxes. I don't think the MUI-Datatables, as of this writing has props like [this feature](https://datatables.net/reference/option/fixedColumns#Examples) that you have linked pertaining to the jQuery datatables.

However, upon looking at [this source code](https://github.com/gregnb/mui-datatables/blob/a382f3e8e850c7fcdd395f8594a5e0afefcaf905/src/components/TableSelectCell.js), we can see that some of the "fixed" columns utilize the CSS [`position: sticky`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#sticky) property. So, one way to implement fixed columns is to style the cells & header cells as such:

```
const columns = [
  {
    name: "Name",
    options: {
      filter: true,
      setCellProps: () => ({
        style: {
          whiteSpace: "nowrap",
          position: "sticky",
          left: "0",
          background: "white",
          zIndex: 100
        }
      }),
      setCellHeaderProps: () => ({
        style: {
          whiteSpace: "nowrap",
          position: "sticky",
          left: 0,
          background: "white",
          zIndex: 101
        }
      })
    }
  },

  ...
```

[image: Edit React MUI-DataTables Fixed Column]

Comment: I am getting error at `=>` and at colons `:` in style object.  I am using VS code.

Comment: This doesn't work with say two sticky columns, you would need to set the `left` on each one and therefor a width.

Comment: background: "inherit" you can use to have the related background